# center the 1 at the top

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int rows, count, num, space;//creating four variables to use for the loops

    cout << "Enter number of rows: ";//prompting the user to input the number of rows
    cin >> rows;

    while (rows < 1 || rows>9)
    {
        cout << "Entry must be between 1 and 9. Please Re-enter the number of rows" << endl; //Asking the user to re-enter the number of rows if it was an invalid input
        cin >> rows;
    }

    for (count = 1; count <= rows; count++) //for function that loops from 1-how many rows the user puts in
    {
        for (space= 1; space < rows; space++) //inner loop that loops from 1 to how many rows the user put in and outputs a space
        {
            cout << "  ";
        }

        for (num = 1; num <= (2*count-1); num++)//the last row of the pyramid has one less than two time sthe number the user input so this loops unitl that is hit
        {
            cout <<count << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n"; //outputs a new line 

    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Number of spaces to print = (center point / 2) - (length of text / 2).

Comment: Having trouble understanding the problem could you please define it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code and you are making a right Angled Triangle of numbers and guessing you need an Isosceles Pyramid of numbers
Refer the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool makeIsoscelesPyramid(const unsigned int& size)
{
    if( size > 9 )
    {
        std::cout<<"Please Enter a positive number less than 9"<<std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        //Number of Space to input
        auto nSpace = size - ( i );
        std::cout << std::string( nSpace, ' ');
        //Times the number is repeated 1, 3, 5 ...
        auto nTimesNumber = (i * 2) + 1;
        //'1'+i could only print till 9 
        std::cout << std::string( nTimesNumber, '1'+i) << std::endl;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int nRows = 0;
    bool bReturn = false;
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter number of rows: \t";
        std::cin>>nRows;
        std::cout<<std::endl;
        bReturn =  makeIsoscelesPyramid(nRows);
    } while( !bReturn );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter number of rows:   5

     1
    222
   33333
  4444444
 555555555
```